# Mypy syntax error with square brackets in generic type hints function, but code runs successfully

Tags: pycharm, mypy, type-hinting, python-typing, python-3.12

I'm experiencing an issue with mypy where it raises a syntax error related to square brackets in the return type annotation of a function. However, the code runs without any issues, and my PyCharm2023.3.3 IDE doesn't show any warnings or errors.

I'm using MacOS and Python 3.12.1.

The code I'm using is derived from the official Python documentation
[Python ORG Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeVarTuple).

```py
def move_first_element_to_last[T, *Ts](tup: tuple[T, *Ts]) -> tuple[*Ts, T]:
    return *tup[1:], tup[0]

a = move_first_element_to_last(tup=(1,))
print(a)  # (1,)

b = move_first_element_to_last(tup=(1, 'spam', 'a'))
print(b)  # ('spam', 'a', 1)

c = move_first_element_to_last(tup=(1, 'spam', 3.0))
print(c)  # ('spam', 3.0, 1)
```

When I execute the command `mypy main.py`, I encounter the following error:

```
main.py:1: error: expected '('  [syntax]
```

However, when I run the code using python main.py, everything functions as expected.

Could someone kindly advise on how to resolve this issue? Additionally, what is a recommended approach for using generic type hints in functions and classes? Thank you in advance! <3

Comment: With an up-to-date `mypy` version you would see the error "PEP 695 generics are not yet supported". Here is the [github issue](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/15238) there isn't much progress on this topic as far as i can see. So you just have to wait until `mypy` supports this or use an alternative